# Display highchart figure in ASP.NET MVC5 view

Tags: javascript, c#, highcharts, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to display a simple chart in my MVC view using highcharts but somehow my javascript is not running. I want to add a chart in the following container.

```
    <div id="container" style="min-width:310px; height:400px; margin:0 auto"></div>
```

I have a separate javascript file that I add in my view.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/lineChart.js"></script>
```

Code for lineChart.js is:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]
});
```

});

I have added all javascript and highchart references but when I run my application, it displays nothing

```
<script src="~/Scripts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

I don't know where the problem is. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: are your references at the top or bottom of the page you want your highcharts to display?

Comment: in your `_Layout` view  i am assuming you have something like `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` at the top? then at the top of your view that you want *Highcharts* to display you put `<script src="~/Scripts/highcharts.js"></script>`
`<script src="~/Scripts/highcharts.src.js"></script>`

Comment: Are you able to go into the brower's inspector tools and see if there are any error messages in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work fine if you meet this conditions. Mu guess is that you failed to do the #2

1. In your layout file, you have defined a section for your page level scripts. Something like `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`
2. In your specific page/view, you are calling/including your page level script which initialize the chart inside the `scripts` section.

   ```
   <div id="container" style="min-width:310px; height:400px; margin:0 auto"></div>

   @section scripts
   {
      <script src="~/Scripts/highcharts.js"></script>
      <script src="~/Scripts/lineChart.js"></script>
   }
   ```
3. And you do not have any javascript errors in your page. Check your browse console to see any possible script errors.
   [Here](http://jsbin.com/tehujizizi/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample using your code & data. Compare it againist the markup produced by razor for your view.